# Android - Out of memory

Tags: android

I know its something i should just google, but maybe you guys can save me sometime.

I tried running a log process in my android app and after sometime i got a out of memory exeption.

I am trying to understand why did it happend?

```
class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int factor = 59;
        int factorSuperNum = 35;
        int num;
        List<Integer> alreadyIn = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j=0; j<5000000; j++){
         alreadyIn.clear();
         for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                num = (int) (1 + (Math.random() * factor) % factor);
                while (alreadyIn.contains(num))
                    num = (int) (1 + (Math.random() * factor) % factor);

                alreadyIn.add(num);
         }
        if(j % 100000 == 0)
            Log.i("SendEmail", j + "" );

        num = (int) (1 + (Math.random() * factorSuperNum) % factorSuperNum);
        alreadyIn.add(num); 

         for (int finalNum : alreadyIn) {
             sb.append(finalNum + " ");
         }
         sb.append("\n");
     }  
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this code is bad at so many cases ...

first `(Math.random() * factor) % factor` why you are multiplying random by factor? do you know that `random % x` is bad?

second OOME is because you add line to StringBuilder in every iteration so after 5M iteration it takes at least 10MB (5M * 20-40bytes)

thrid for taking 5 from factor you can use ArrayList with range from 1 to factor and shuffle it and take firs 5 elments:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class LOLOLOLOLOL
{
    static final int F = 59;
    static final int FSN = 35;
    static final ArrayList<Integer> range1toF = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static final Random rnd = new Random();
    static{
        for(int i = 1; i < F; i++)
            range1toF.add(i);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out); //or from File
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            Collections.shuffle(range1toF, rnd);
            for(int j = 0; j< 5; j++){
                ps.print(range1toF.get(j));
                ps.print(", ");
            }
            ps.println(rnd.nextInt(FSN - 1) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```